# Iam Getting b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() ERROR

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am creating a simple app in eclipse but I am getting error at this line

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

please have a look at the entire program

```
package com.example.activity2;

public class Main extends Activity {
    //Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
}
}
```

this was the program and iam getting this error..please help me in this issue.

Comment: try to press `ctrl+shift+o` in your code and see what happen

Comment: have u import ? import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: show your import statements.

Comment: Hover your mouse on OnClickListener() and eclipse (if your using it) would show a menu. First option would be Import related package. Click on it. Problem solved!

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and it was solved by Nik's suggestion to add the import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import this:  `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
.......
.......
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
b.setOnClickListener
        (
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {your code...;}
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

or You can make simple click method
in xml

```
android:onClick="MyClick"
```

and in java code do like

```
public void MyClick(View v) {

  //do your work here
    }
```